# Validate a jwt token with express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, stripe-payments

Ive been getting a lot of errors saying

```
POST http://localhost:4000/api/payment/create-checkout-session 403 (Forbidden)

AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 403', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config
: 
"Request failed with status code 403"
name
: 
"AxiosError"
request 
{data: 'A token is required', status: 403, statusText: 'Forbidden', headers: Axios
```

I think it has something to do with my token validation, this is the file for token validation

```
const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['Authorization'];
    console.log("Token: ", token);
  
    if (!token) {
      return res.status(403).send("A token is required");
    }
  
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      req.user = decoded;
      next();
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(401).send("Invalid token, this is the error message:" + err);
    }
  };
  
  module.exports = verifyToken;
```

this is the file that is making the axios post request

```
const token = Cookies.get("token");
  console.log("token from catalog " + token)

  const checkout = () => {
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:4000/api/payment/create-checkout-session",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
      }
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.ok) return response.json();
      return response.json().then(json => Promise.reject(json))
    })
    .then(({ url }) => {
      window.location = url;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

this is the express file that the axios is posting too

```
require('./middleware')




router.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {

  const { items } = req.body;

  // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
    currency: "usd",
    automatic_payment_methods: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  });

  res.send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });

})

module.exports = router;
```

is there a better way to validate a toke, or am I missing a header or something in my axios request?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log("Token: ", token);`

Answer (score 1):

Without digging too much into your code I think that your validation is fine.

You are getting the 403 because there is no `Authorization` header. I am going to assume that you are using express. Even though you specified that the header is `Authorization` with a capital `A`, in express to access that request header you have to look for `req.headers.authorization` with a lower-cased `a`.

I ran a simple app:

```js
import express from "express";

const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("hi there 3000");
});

app.post("/auth", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.headers);
  res.status(200).send(req.headers);
});
```

Then curled the following: `➜  curl --header "Authorization: Bearer something" -I -X POST http://localhost:3000/auth`

The `req.headers` is as follows:

```
{
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  'user-agent': 'curl/7.79.1',
  accept: '*/*',
  authorization: 'Bearer something'
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: i set the authorization header in my validation to this, req.headers['authorization'];. the token isn't undefined anymore but now its coming back with a 401 unauthorized and its saying 'Invalid token, this is the error message:JsonWebTokenError: invalid token'

Comment: Can you share more information about how the token is generated and what library are you using to verify it?